# Название события и свойство объекта одно и тоже?

Tags: javascript, объекты, события, mixins

В данном коде  eventName является одновременно событием и защищённым свойством объекта _eventHandlers куда записываются функции выполняющиеся при наступлении события?

```js
Примесь eventMixin, реализующая события:

var eventMixin = {

  /**
   * Подписка на событие
   * Использование:
   *  menu.on('select', function(item) { ... }
   */
  on: function(eventName, handler) {
    if (!this._eventHandlers) this._eventHandlers = {};
    if (!this._eventHandlers[eventName]) {
      this._eventHandlers[eventName] = [];
    }
    this._eventHandlers[eventName].push(handler);
  },

  /**
   * Прекращение подписки
   *  menu.off('select',  handler)
   */
  off: function(eventName, handler) {
    var handlers = this._eventHandlers && this._eventHandlers[eventName];
    if (!handlers) return;
    for(var i=0; i<handlers.length; i++) {
      if (handlers[i] == handler) {
        handlers.splice(i--, 1);
      }
    }
  },

  /**
   * Генерация события с передачей данных
   *  this.trigger('select', item);
   */
  trigger: function(eventName /*, ... */) {

    if (!this._eventHandlers || !this._eventHandlers[eventName]) {
      return; // обработчиков для события нет
    }

    // вызвать обработчики
    var handlers = this._eventHandlers[eventName];
    for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
      handlers[i].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }

  }
};
Здесь есть три метода:

.on(имя события, функция) – назначает функцию к выполнению при наступлении события с данным именем. Такие функции хранятся в защищённом свойстве объекта _eventHandlers.
.off(имя события, функция) – удаляет функцию из списка предназначенных к выполнению.
.trigger(имя события, аргументы) – генерирует событие, при этом вызываются все назначенные на него функции, и им передаются аргументы.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eventName` - это строка, *название* события и свойства (почему "защищенного"?) объекта `this._eventHandlers`. Они одинаково называются для удобства.

---

> А зачем тут в переменную записывать 2 этих операнда
>
> `var handlers = this._eventHandlers && this._eventHandlers[eventName];`

Здесь код пытается получить массив обработчиков события `eventName`. Если свойства `this._eventHandlers` еще нет, первый операнд вернет `undefined`, что в булевском смысле значит `false`. Второй операнд в этом случае нет смысла вычислять, и выражение справа от `=` вернет `undefined`. Ошибки доступа к свойству несуществующего объекта не будет.

Если свойство `this._eventHandlers` уже есть, выражение вернет `this._eventHandlers[eventName]`, что тоже может быть `undefined` - это проверяется в следующей строчке

```
if (!handlers) return;
```

Comment: А зачем тут в переменную записывать 2 этих операндаvar handlers = this._eventHandlers && this._eventHandlers[eventName];почему не достаточно только название свойства,или это для того сделано что вдруг функции которые нужно удалить.. записались ещё куда-нибудь в объект?