# Что это за х в методе filter?

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

что в данном фрагменте означает `[1]`? И почему `e` и `a[i]` не одно и то же? Это же означает элемент массива?

```
firstNonConsecutive = 
  a => (a = a.filter((e, i) => e - a[i - 1] !== 1)[1]) === undefined ? null : a;
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/903669/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5

Comment: отметил)если вы об этом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[1]` - означает второй элемент массива, полученного в результате фильтрации.

`e` и `a[i]` - одно и то же, элемент массива.

```js
firstNonConsecutive = 
  a => (a = a.filter((e, i) => e - a[i - 1] !== 1)[1]) === undefined ? null : a;
  
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([1,2,6,4,5]));
```

Comment: а почему он именно 2й то?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl Потому что первый - будет всегда. Это первый элемент массива, для него `e - a[i - 1] !== 1` всегда равно `true`.

Comment: тогда почему не 3й или не 4й  да любой кроме первого?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl Наверное потому, что функция называется - "первый, который не по порядку".

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl Пожалуйста. Успехов.